# Complexity of sorting n/logn sequences of an array size n

Tags: arrays, sorting, time-complexity

Given an array in the size of N (the array contains whole numbers), I wish to sort the array but only on lengths of log(n) in the array, so by the end the array will have n/logn sequences (in the size of logn each sequence) that are sorted.

My idea was to use the algorithm of MergeSort which in worst case of time complexity runs O(nlogn).
But since I am only sorting lengths of logn in the array, the time complexity should be O(log(n)*log(log(n))) because I am not in fact going through the entire length of N.

So MergeSort will be preformed in that case n/logn times.
Is it safe to assume that the overall time complexity of this action would be (n/logn)*O(log(n)*log(log(n))) => O(n*log(log(n)))?

Comment: If your data is not to big then quicksort is a good option than merge sort. Quicksort worst case is N square but there is very very very very less even not possible to fall in worst case but other things like same array and locality of reference make it more powerful and fast than merge sort. but merge sort is good for big amount data because it provides you virtual memory usage as well.

Comment: Yes, O(n log log n) is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is correct: sorting `n / log n` chunks of the array of size `log n` can be done in `O(n log(log n))`.

However, if your entire array is not that big in the first place (say a few thousand elements max), the `log n` chunks will be quite small, in which case it is actually more efficient to use [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#:%7E:text=However%2C%20insertion%20sort%20is%20one,be%20determined%20experimentally%20and%20depends) rather than an algorithm like merge sort or Quicksort.